# Convergence of random variable divided by constant that goes to inifinity

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I have read in some book the following Lemma:

> For any random variable $X$ and for any sequence $c_n$, with $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = \infty$ the following is true:
>   $$P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n^{-1}X=0\right)=1$$

I am wondering why it is true, and if it is - how to prove it.
I tried Borel-Cantelli:
$$A_n = \left\{w: c_n^{-1}X\neq 0\right\}$$ then $P(A_n\mbox{ i.o.})$
if 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)<\infty$. But what if $X=\infty$ w.p $1$? Isn't it a problem?

Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing probabilistic in there, just the realization that $$\left\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n^{-1}X(\omega)=0\right\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid |X(\omega)|<\infty\},$$ hence the exercise implicitely assumes that "random variable" means in particular "almost surely finite" (a common choice).

Comment: ok. so how can I prove it?

Comment: *By reading my comment*.